# Getting incorrect Android.Systems.OsConstants values in .NET

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I'm working on adding CPU monitoring to the Android portion of my Xamarin Forms app. I'm following the instructions found on [this page](https://eng.lyft.com/monitoring-cpu-performance-of-lyfts-android-applications-4e36fafffe12), and currently have the following code written:

```
var self = new Java.IO.RandomAccessFile("/proc/self/stat", "r");
string[] info = self.ReadLine().Split(" ");

int clockSpeedHz = Android.Systems.OsConstants.ScClkTck;
int numCores = Android.Systems.OsConstants.ScNprocessorsConf;

double uptimeSec = SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() / 1000.0;
long startTime = long.Parse(info[21]);

double cpuTimeSeconds = (long.Parse(info[13]) + long.Parse(info[14]) + long.Parse(info[15]) + long.Parse(info[16])) / (double)clockSpeedHz;
double processTimeSeconds = uptimeSec - (startTime / clockSpeedHz);
double avgUsagePercent = (100 * cpuTimeSeconds / processTimeSeconds) / numCores;

return avgUsagePercent;
```

After running this, the avgUsagePercent value doesn't make sense (ex. average CPU usage is (-2*10^-8)%). Looking at the numbers, it seems like the issue is with the calls to `Android.Systems.OsConstants`. According to those values, my CPU has 96 cores, with a clock speed of 6 Hz. Setting those numbers to the expected values of my device (8 cores, 100 Hz) provides much more realistic values (2-10% CPU usage). I can't rely on these numbers, however, as this app will be loaded onto different devices that might not have these values.

Does anyone know what the correct way to get `Android.Systems.OsConstants` values is? Taking a look at other constants in this namespace, it seems like these might just be indices in a list, since they're all unique and roughly follow numerical order. I'm wondering if the .NET implementation of this namespace requires some function to convert the index to a value, and I'm just not aware of it. Otherwise if there's a different implementation to access these values, I'm open to using those methods as well.

Comment: you mention "this page" without providing any link

Comment: @Jason Whoops, you are absolutely right. I've fixed that now

Comment: Did you look at [OsConstants Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.systems.osconstants?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12)?  Though the doc isn't very informative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are constants that are used in `sysconf` to return the actual values of the device's hardware (see Linux man page if you need to review `sysconf` features):

Incorrect:

```
int numCores = Android.Systems.OsConstants.ScNprocessorsConf;
```

Correct:

```
long numCores = Android.Systems.Os.Sysconf(Android.Systems.OsConstants.ScNprocessorsConf)
```